# Getting runtime error in linked list implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was trying to implement the insert function of singly linked list.
My implement function should insert the newnode at the head position rather than tail.
when i try to compile this c++ code i get runtime error.

here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

struct node {
int data ;
struct node * next ;
};

struct node *head = NULL;

// inserting newnode at head position rather than tail
void insert (struct node* root , int idata) {
    if (root == NULL){
        root->next = NULL;
        root->data = idata;
    }
    
    else {
        struct node * newnode = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node) ) ;
        newnode->data = idata ;
        newnode->next = root ;
        root = newnode ;

    }

}


int main () {
    insert (head, 20) ;

    return 0;
}
```

but i m unable to understand why am i getting compilation error. Kindly help !!

Comment: You didn't assign memory for head. But your are assigning data to them inside NULL check condition.

Comment: *"when i try to compile this c++ code i get runtime error."* -- No, if the error occurs when you try to *compile*, then it would be a *compilation* error. *Run*time errors occur when you try to *run* your program.

Comment: What is the error, and which  line triggers it? What are the values of your variables when the error occurs (assuming it really is a runtime error)?

Comment: " sigsegv error " this is the error i got when i run the code on an online SPOJ platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error caused by below line;

```
struct node *head = NULL;
```

first in c++, you don't need `struct` to declare objects.

second you can declare `head` inside `main` local scope to avoid global pollution.

third, the main cause of your `error`, you must allocate memory to access any object.

so, change your `main` and `insert` function to below.

```
int main () 
{
    node* head = NULL;
    insert(&head, 20) ;
    insert(&head, 30 );

    delete head;
    return 0;
}
```

and in `insert` function, use double pointer to pass `address` of `head`, so the change you made inside function affects the actual `head`.

```
void insert (node** root , int idata) {
        if ( (*root) == NULL )
        {
            (*root) = new node;
            (*root)->data = idata;
            (*root)->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {        
            struct node * newnode = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node) ) ;
            newnode->data = idata ;
            newnode->next = *root ;
            *root = newnode;
        }

}
```

Comment: thnx this was a bit helpful. But why is it necessary to declare head in main function ?? I was planning to declare head outside main function so that my head pointer gets updated every time we call insert () function. [though i m comfortable with your logic of double pointer]

Comment: why is my approach wrong ?? when i created the head pointer with global scope and tried to pass head using pass by reference in insert ()  function  ?? why  is my approach faulty ??

Comment: It's not declaring in global scope the error caused, error was due to not allocating any memory and try to access the null pointer. if you look at my `insert` function 4th line, I have allocated memory to `head`, then accessed the object.

Comment: ` newnode->next = *root ; `  this is your 11th line in the insert function, why can't we do it in the followinf way :  ` newnode->next = (*root)->next `      as (*root) gives us the address being stored in head pointer

Comment: That way you assigning your `root's next` pointer to `newnode's` `next`, but what you wanted, your `newnode` to be your `head`. what we wrote in our in first place is actually what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

change the following in your if block of **insert** function

```
if (root == NULL){
        root = new node;  //this must be added to allocate memory for root node.
        root->next = NULL;
        root->data = idata;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any compiler errors. But there are a couple logic errors

```cpp
void insert (struct node* root , // the root node is passed by reference
                                 // the pointer is not. So when you change where
                                 // root points, the caller won't know
             int idata) {
    if (root == NULL){
        root->next = NULL; // root points at NULL, a special parking location that, 
                           // on every target I've coded for, sits in a reserved memory
                           // area that will kill a program that reads from or writes 
                           // to it. Technically this would be  undefined behaviour, 
                           // but the results are extremely reliable to help you find 
                           // bugs.
        root->data = idata;
    }
    
    else {
        struct node * newnode = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node) ) ;
                       // malloc is almost always the wrong choice in C++
                       // use new. malloc requires you to be certain you 
                       // got the size right and does not call constructors. 
                       // It gives you memory, not objects.
        newnode->data = idata ;
        newnode->next = root ;
        root = newnode ;

    }

}
```

Now if you always want to insert at `root`, there's no need for an if. There is only one place for the node to go.

```cpp
void insert (struct node*& root , //reference to pointer
             int idata) {
    root = new node {idata, root}; // this is aggregate initialization
}
```

or

```cpp
node * insert (struct node* root , 
             int idata) {
    return new node {idata, root};
}
```

In the first, the `node` pointer provided by the caller as `root` is updated with the new `node` which in turn points to the old `root` `node`. In the second, a new `node` is allocated and pointed at `root` ands the returned to the caller. The caller uses this version something like

```
head = insert(head, 20);
```

[Documentation for aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

[Documentation for Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)